# How to call data from rows in R

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a csv file in R but I can't call the rows with $. Is it only works on Columns or I am using the wrong function.

Comment: `df["rowname",]` is the most direct way (e.g. `mtcars["Mazda RX4",]`) but this leads to a very poor workflow.

Comment: *"Is it only works on Columns"*? Yes, it's only columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can put the rows into a list and name each element to use `$`. Otherwise the other option is as @Phil pointed out, to use `mtcars['Maserati Bora',]`. It's more common to use column names tho, in fact rownames in tibbles are  deprecated.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars_rownames <- rownames(mtcars) %>%
    map(~ `[`(mtcars, .x, )) %>%
    set_names(map(.,~ rownames(.x)))

mtcars_rownames$`Maserati Bora`
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> Maserati Bora  15   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8

mtcars_rownames$`Datsun 710`
#>             mpg cyl disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710 22.8   4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>